# How to move a linux container to a remote server running proxmox 7.0?

Tags: linux, migration, proxmox, lxc, lxd

I am currently in the process of migrating a server running several linux containers to a server managed by proxmox. In the past when i moved a linux container to a different host i just used the LXD API, simplestreams protocol and executed a `lxc copy` command - quite simple. But how is it done if the remote is managed by proxmox so that the migrated container is known to proxmox afterwards?

Comment: Have you checked this guide https://amoldighe.github.io/2018/07/24/proxmox-move/ and this script https://www.jamescoyle.net/how-to/2863-move-proxmox-container-to-different-storage-2